Bayesian posterior predictive distribution for a random walk with drift
Suppose we have a random walk with drift $$ x_i - x_{i-1} = \mu + \varepsilon_i,$$ where the error terms $\varepsilon_i$ are i.i.d. Gaussian with the same variance $\sigma^2$. Given a sequence of $t+1$ observations $x_0, \ldots, x_t$, I would like to know the posterior predictive distribution for the $\tau$-steps ahead forecast $p(x_{t + \tau} | x_0, \ldots, x_t)$, for any $\tau \geq 1$.
As an initial simplification, let’s replace the $x_i$’s with their first differences $y_i = x_i - x_{i-1}$, so that we have a constant mean process
$$ y_i = \mu + \varepsilon_i.$$
Then letting $z = \sum_{i=t+1}^{t + \tau} y_i = x_{t+\tau} - x_t$, we see that $p(x_{t + \tau} | x_0, \ldots, x_t)$ is equal to $p(z | y_1, \ldots, y_t)$ shifted by $x_t$, so it suffices to compute the latter distribution.
Now with $ y = y_1, \ldots, y_t$, we have
$$ p(z | y) = \int p(z | \mu, \sigma^2) p(\mu, \sigma^2 | y) \,d\mu \, d\sigma^2.$$
Because of the independence assumption and the fact that
$$z = \sum_{i=t+1}^{t + \tau} y_i = \sum_{i=t+1}^{t + \tau} (\mu + \varepsilon_i) = \tau \mu + \sum_{i=t+1}^{t + \tau} \varepsilon_i,$$
we have
$$p(z | \mu, \sigma^2) = \mathrm{N}(\tau \mu, \tau\sigma^2).$$
Moreover, assuming the standard improper priors for $\mu$ and $\sigma$, their posterior distribution is
$$p(\mu, \sigma^2 | y) \propto \sigma^{-t-2} \exp \Big( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} [(t-1)s^2 + t(\bar{y} - \mu)^2] \Big),$$
where $\bar{y} = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^t y_i$ is the sample mean and $s^2 = \frac{1}{t-1}\sum_{i=1}^t (y_i - \bar{y})^2$ is the sample variance.

When I try to use these expressions to compute the integral, I get stuck. In particular, I tried expanding the term $(z - \tau \mu)^2$ in $p(z | \mu, \sigma^2)$ as $((z - \tau \bar{y}) + (\tau \bar{y} - \tau \mu))^2$, but I wasn't sure what to do with the 'cross terms'.
For $\tau = 1$, $p(z | y)$ is a $t$-distribution with location $\bar{y}$, scale $(1 + \frac{1}{t})^{\frac{1}{2}}s$, and $t - 1$ degrees of freedom (Gelman et al, Bayesian data analysis, pg. 66). So I suspect that in general, $p(z | y)$ is also a $t$-distribution. The location would be $\tau \bar{y}$, and degrees of freedom would be the same, and the scale would be some function of $\tau$.


The model in your first sentence doesn't appear to be a random walk at all, but rather a constant mean process, yet that sentence describes it as such. Please write it in a way that's not conflating the process-increments with the random walk itself

As Glen_b pointed out and I'll just add to, the model you wrote is called the constant mean model  which I've seen in quality control type texts. But, if you changed your $\mu$ to $y_{i-1}$ , then you'd have a RW so maybe it's a typo ?

Also, note that the summed expression for $z$ is only correct if $\mu$ is replaced by $y_{i-1}$ so that, to me, is  more evidence that it might be a typo ? More often in the RW, the observation at time $t$, $y_{t}$, is written as the sum of the $\epsilon_{i}$ so $ y_{t} = \sum_{i=0}^{t} \epsilon_{i}$.

Thanks @Glen_b, I've fixed the wording.

@mlofton, why is the definition of $z$ incorrect? The question I'm intending to ask is, suppose we've made $t$ observations of a constant mean process, what is the posterior predictive distribution for the sum of the next $\tau$ observations?

Hi Owen: I'll try to put it in an answer but I want to make sure that I understand what you're asking.  My understanding is that you want to make a prediction for $y_t$ at time $(t + \tau)$. So, you want to predict $y_{t+\tau}$ and the model is what you wrote at the beginning which is a constant mean model ?

Hi Owen: I won't try to answer now because it's still not quite clear to me  ? The model says that the mean is $\mu$ rather than $y_{t-1}$ like in an RW. So, if you just want the sum for your own purposes, that's fine. But, if that's the case, would you not want to update the posterior each time a new observation, $y_{t+i}$ comes in ? So, an update for the  posterior distribution of $y_{t+i}$ at each time $(t+i)$ ?

Owen: Note that the reason I asked about the sum is because, in an RW, the sum actually is $y_{t+\tau}$. But forget that I brought that up because it sounds like your model is not an RW but you still want the sum which is fine. My only question now is why would you not want to update each time a new observation arrives ?

Thanks @mlofton. I've reformulated the question to reflect my original motivation for asking it, which was indeed about random walks. Hopefully it's now clear what I'm trying to do!

Hi Owen: So, it seems that you changed the formulaton so you are considering that the difference in $x_t$ is a constant with non-zero mean so it follows a constant mean model. Clearly, this is the same as $x_t$ being a random walk with non-zero mean. But, if you are sure that you want the sum of the predictions of the differences as the object you are predicting, then $\mu$ goes away. This is because you are predicting $ \sum_{i=t+1}^{t+\tau} y_{i}$, which would be the sum of the $\epsilon_i$.  Therefore the mean of the summed process of the differences would be $0$ rather than $n \mu$.

So, assuming Xi'an's derivation is correct ( and I'm confident that it is. I've seen enough of Xi'an's derivations to know that he owns anything bayesian and then some ), the terms involving $\mu$ should be zero.

To be honest, I'm not sure how the mean of the summed process being zero effects the derivation of the posterior. That's a better question for Xi'an.

Basically, what I am saying, albeit in a very confusing way ,is that your modified formulation implies the equality: :  $\sum_{i =t+1}^{t+\tau} y_i = \sum_{i =t+1}^{t+\tau} \epsilon_{i}$. The original formulation did not imply this but it almost did !!!!!

Hi @mlofton, I'm not sure I understand. According to the definition of $y_i$ above, $\sum_{i=t+1}^{t+\tau} y_i = \sum_{i=t+1}^{t+\tau} (\mu + \varepsilon_i) = \tau \mu + \sum_{i=t+1}^{t+\tau}  \varepsilon_i$.

I'm not an expert on random walks (clearly!) but I don't think $\mu$ is the mean of the $x_i$'s. A random walk with drift is not a stationary process - there's a trend after all - so in particular it doesn't have a constant mean.

Hi Owen: I'll write an answer to show why it becomes the sum of the $\epsilon_i$.

You should not change the question in such a significant way! The usual recommendation on X validated is to ask a different question to avoid nullifying answers to earlier versions (that are not visible anymore).

@Xi'an I don't think I've invalidated your answer. The definitions of $y$ and $z$ to which your answer referred have not changed.

One derives from
$$p(z|\mu, \sigma^2 )p(\mu, \sigma^2 | y) \propto \sigma^{-t-1-2} \exp \Big( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} [(t-1)s^2 + t(\bar{y} - \mu)^2+\tau^{-1}(z-\tau\mu)^2] \Big)$$
that
$$t(\bar{y} - \mu)^2+\tau^{-1}(z-\tau\mu)^2=(t+\tau)\mu^2-2\mu(t\bar y+z)+t\bar y^2+\tau^{-1}z^2\\
=\underbrace{(t+\tau)\mu^2-2\mu(t\bar y+z)+(t+\tau)^{-1}(t\bar y+z)^2}\\\overbrace{-(t+\tau)^{-1}(t\bar y+z)^2+t\bar y^2+\tau^{-1}z^2}^\text{perfect squares}\\
%=(t+\tau)[\mu-(t\bar y+z)/(t+\tau)]^2+t\bar y^2+\tau^{-1}z^2-(t\bar %y+z)^2/(t+\tau)\\
=(t+\tau)[\mu-(t\bar y+z)/(t+\tau)]^2+t\tau(\bar y-\tau^{-1}z)^2/(t+\tau)$$
Hence, integrating out $\mu$,
$$p(z|\sigma^2 )p(\sigma^2 | y) \propto \sigma^{-t-2} \exp \Big( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} [(t-1)s^2 + t\tau(\bar y-\tau^{-1}z)^2/(t+\tau)] \Big)$$
and integrating out $\sigma$
$$p(z|y)\propto\Big((t-1)s^2 + t\tau(\bar y-\tau^{-1}z)^2/(t+\tau)\Big)^{-t/2}$$
which indeed results into a Student's predictive with $(t-1)$ degrees of freedom.

So we get a $t$-distribution with location $\tau \bar{y}$, scale $s^2(\tau + \tau^2/t)$ and $t-1$ degrees of freedom. That's exactly the result I was hoping for, thanks!

Xi'an: Thank you for your answer. Do you know of a book or paper that goes into the details of where you say integrating out "parameter". Thanks.

Xi'an: The formulation changed a little ( see comments between myself and Owen ). I don't know if you want to deal with the modified formulation. If not, I understand but  if you could provide any references or sources for the integration parts, maybe Owen and I could solve it without your intervention. But that's not claiming that I wouldn't prefer your intervention  !!!! Thanks either way.

I also shouldn't speak for Owen in above. Given what you did with the original formulation, maybe he is able to solve the modified one accordingly. I don't know.

@mlofton: this is why question contents should not be changed in significant ways, as is the case here, and thus why asking a new question is preferred on Stack Exchange. I do not understand the question about integration, any standard calculus textbook dealing with integration or measure theory covers maginalisation

@mlofton, I reference I find helpful is Section 3.2 of Bayesian Data Analysis by Gelman et al: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/. The calculation there is essentially a simpler version of Xi'an's calculation.

Xi'an: I agree about asking a new question. I have Zellner's classic book somewhere. That probably has the marginalization details in it so no problem.

Owen: I don't have time to go through the details of Section 3.2 right now but thanks for the link. I definitely will check it out. I can't tell if you are now okay with figuring out how to change what Xi'an did earlier  so that it fits your new formulation ? If not, I'll try to look at 3.2 this weekend. That's the earliest I could possibly get to it and even then I don't know if I can figure it out. Maybe some other bayesian guru not named Xi'an can take a look at it sooner ?

Owen: Two things. 1) I will write out why it's the sum of the $\epsilon_i$ late tonight. 2) As far as taking what I said and trying to do the similar thing that Xi'an did , check out Zellner's "Bayesian Inference in Econometrics". If you can't get a hold of that book, then David Giles wrote a nice more compact version of Zellner's book here: https://web.uvic.ca/~dgiles/blog/Zellner.pdf He provides some of the gory details for the type of thing Xi'an did but I don't know if he tackles your problem exactly.

@mlofton I don't think Xi'an's answer needs to be modified at all, since I'm not convinced by your objection: it follows directly from the definition that $z = \tau \mu + \sum_{i= t+1}^{t+\tau} \varepsilon_i$.

Hi Owen: You are ABSOLUTELY correct. I must have been zoning out for the last couple fo days so forget what I said about the prediction being  just the sum of the $\epsilon$. My sincere apologies for leading you astray. I still don't follow Xi'an's derivation but I'm gonna work on it as time permits. No more peeps from me as far as this problem is concerned. I think, thanks to Xi'an, you should be good now. I'm not but I'll try to make heads or tails out of it at some point.
